# How to keep sidebar and header fixed with overflow on content

Tags: html, css

How to only make `#content` scrollable but keep `#header` and `#sidebar` fixed?

And is `flexbox` the best way to do it?

https://jsfiddle.net/3pnj1k5b/

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#page-app {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

#header {
  height: 60px;
  background: pink;
}

#body {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}

#content {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-app">
  <section id="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </section>
  <div id="body">
    <header id="header">
      header
    </header>
    <section id="content">
      content<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `flex` or `grid` would be your go-to layouts for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's `position:fixed` that fixes element to their position. It was basically what I've added.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#page-app {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 2
}

#header {
  height: 60px;
  background: pink;
  position: fixed;
  padding-left: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#body {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}

#content {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-app">
  <section id="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </section>
  <div id="body">
    <header id="header">
      header
    </header>
    <section id="content">
      content<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b content
      <br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b

    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You probably want to add a top margin to the content section so the content isn't hidden under the fixed header

Comment: The difference between this answer and @Kameron's is the scroll in this one is on the window vs the scroll on the content div itself on the other answer

Answer (score 0):

Make the `html,body` `height: 100%;`. Then add a `max-height` to `#page-app`. Then make `#sidebar` and `#header` `position: sticky;`.  Finally, just set the `height` of `#content` to be `100%` minus the height of the `header`. In your case I used a `calc` to set that height. See below:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#page-app {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: sticky;
}

#header {
  height: 60px;
  background: pink;
  position: sticky;
}

#body {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}

#content {
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

```html
<div id="page-app">
  <section id="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </section>
  <div id="body">
    <header id="header">
      header
    </header>
    <section id="content"> content<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the #header `position: sticky` and the #body scrollable with `overflow-y: scroll;`

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/emekaorji/pen/rNdOEvj)

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#page-app{
  display:flex;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#sidebar{
  width:200px;
  height: 100%;
  background:blue;
}

#header{
  height:60px;
  background:pink;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#body{
  flex:1;
  background:green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-app">
  <section id="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </section>
  <div id="body">
    <header id="header">
      header
    </header>
    <section id="content">
      content<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```